# Is it possible to use Firefox Add-on SDK from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

Is it possible to use Firefox Add-on SDK from a Greasemonkey script? In particular I want to use the sidebar from `sdk/ui`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui

Answer (score 1):

No, Greasemonkey script is content-script, see this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

> content scripts can't use the SDK's APIs (no access to globals exports, require) but can access web content

But it can communicating with the add-on script.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Userscript is a content script which is ran in a sandbox and can only access certain `GM_*` apis. It can only modify webpage but not the ui or chrome page.

You may need [userChromeJs](http://userchromejs.mozdev.org/) or create your own add-on to do that.

BTW, if you want to add a menu shortcut in userscript for certain website, you may try [`GM_registerMenuCommand`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_registerMenuCommand).